# How to change docker0 setting in CoreOS?

Tags: docker, coreos

I am using CoreOS on my ESX (without cloud config - I have't any cloud provider). I need to change the private ip range for docker containers because they can't response to network that uses same ip range 172.x.x.x (e.g. 172.17.0.1)

PS:

```
# ifconfig docker0
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::42:5aff:fe5b:be55  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:5a:5b:be:55  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 446773  bytes 34183812 (32.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 738428  bytes 1223177292 (1.1 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [systemd drop-in](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-drop-in-units.html) and the DOCKER_OPTS environment variable to add or tweak docker flags.

Here's an [example for enabling TLS](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-docker.html#drop-in-configuration), but the process is the same. Manually or via cloud-config, create `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10-docker0.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment="DOCKER_OPTS=--bip=1.2.3.4/24 --fixed-cidr=1.2.3.4/24"
```

Use the [docker bridge docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/) for the correct values for your usecase.